# removing vertical space between boxes

Tags: spacing, boxes

I need to include an image followed immediately by a horizontal line in my document. The image and line need to span the *entire* width of the page. There should be no padding around either of them and no vertical space between them. Using boxes, here's what I have so far:

```
\noindent\makebox[\linewidth]{\includegraphics[scale=1.0]{/tmp/image.png}}
\noindent\makebox[\linewidth]{\textcolor{tone}{\rule{\paperwidth}{5pt}}}
```

This leaves a small vertical space between the image and the line. I tried inserting a `\vspace`:

```
\noindent\makebox[\linewidth]{\includegraphics[scale=1.0]{/tmp/image.png}}
\vspace{-5mm}
\noindent\makebox[\linewidth]{\textcolor{tone}{\rule{\paperwidth}{5pt}}}
```

Somehow this affects the space *below* the line, not above it. What is the correct solution here?

Comment: There's an interline skip (very small, be recognizable), you have to remove it with `{....  \offinterlineskip...}` where `...` stands for your box commands. Use a `{}` pair around this otherwise you would get into trouble

Comment: @ChristianHupfer: that works, thanks! Care to make that an answer?